# Cant map firebase documents to the total number with rxjs

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs

I try to map with rxjs my shopping cart items to the number of items.
The data is stored in Cloud Firestore and I receive it over the collection.

[image]

Unfortunately, I got really stuck on this. Would be great if anyone had a suggestion for me
hot to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Is it right to return the `Promise` of an `Observable`?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `x` is not your shopping cart, it is a snapshot object.

You need dig into the snapshot object to get your cart payload:

```
return this.dbcollection('shopping-cards).doc(id).snapshotChanges().pipe(
   map(snapshot => shapshot.payload.doc),   // not sure on exact format, but something like this
   map(cart => new ShappingCartModel(cart.items)
);
```